# Extract number of tables in PDF

Tags: java, itext, extract

I am trying to use iText to find out the number of tables present in a pdf file using java, however with no success can anyone let me know the right direction to look in.

Comment: itext provides you with the tools to do document analysis. You'll have to use these tools to do the analysis yourself. First you'll have to define, though, how tables are to be recognized.  Especially in case of tables without separating lines that seems quite a challenge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PDF is tagged, you can inspect the `StructTreeRoot` for table structures. If your PDF isn't tagged, there are no tables in your PDF. You may see tables with the naked eye, but as far as the PDF file is concerned, there are only lines and snippets of text, *no tables!*

A PDF that isn't tagged, doesn't know anything about its structure! Extracting tables from a PDF that doesn't contain a `StructTreeRoot` is as possible as extracting the original full carrots from carrot soup. If that's what you want to do, then hopefully my metaphor explains why you're asking for something that is impossible (which explains why you don't find any answers).

How do you find out if a PDF is Tagged? Open the PDF in Adobe Reader and click File > Document Properties. Somewhere at the bottom of the Properties tab, there's an entry that indicates **Tagged PDF: No** or **Tagged PDF: Yes**.

Comment: Good answer, but it's difficult not impossible

Comment: Regarding "it's difficult not impossible": I agree and I don't agree. I agree that you can detect *some* tables if you throw enough code at the problem: e.g. parse the content streams for linear paths that enclose text. But that won't work for all kinds of tables, because some tables don't have any visual borders. What are you going to detect in cases like that? White space? What if such a table has a part with a table-wide colspan? Will that count as one table? Or as two tables separated by text? It's impossible to do without any error.